# How to fix login and logout in jinja template based on user session?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, jinja2

My login system is working well in terms of connecting with the DB. However, somehow my jinja template is showing `account/logout` as soon as a user loads the website instead of `login/register`. But when users go to `account` it goes to `login`. In other words, it's showing the other way around.

I have done the conditional as follow:

```
{% if session['email'] == None %}
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{url_for('login')}}">Login</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{url_for('register')}}">Register</a>
          </li>
          <!--WILL DISPLAY HOME/LOGIN/REGISTER WHEN LOGGED IN-->
          {% else %}
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-success" href="{{url_for('user')}}">Account</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{url_for('logout')}}">Logout</a>
          </li>
          {% endif %}
```

In addition, I am almost sure that the template is not the problem, rather the login function that I am trying to fix but with no success:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'GET': 
        return render_template('login.html')
    else:
        user = mongo.db.user
        login_user = user.find_one({
        'email': request.form.get('email'), 
        'password':request.form.get('password'
        )})

        if login_user:
            session['email'] = login_user['email']
            session['name'] = login_user['name']
            return redirect(url_for('user'))

        return 'Invalid username or password combination'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this issue is as follow:

```
{% if not session['email'] %}
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{url_for('login')}}">Login</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{url_for('register')}}">Register</a>
          </li>
          <!--WILL DISPLAY HOME/LOGIN/REGISTER WHEN LOGGED IN-->
          {% else %}
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-success" href="{{url_for('user')}}">Account</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{url_for('logout')}}">Logout</a>
          </li>
          {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that email is not an attribute of session making session['email'] be undefined.

If condition can be

```
{% if session['email'] is not defined or session['email']|length  == 0 %}
```

I would rather make the if condition be more positive per de-morgans

```
{% if session['email'] is defined and session['email']|length %}
// logout template
```

[Undefined Types](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/api/#undefined-types)

Comment: @EliasPrado I was saying that this can happen if 'email' is not a key in session.
eg.  session = {'name': 'abc'} is a dictionary with no key 'email' and de-referencing 'email' as session['email'] will not generate the None value but will be an exception. You cannot check for equality with None for those values. 

The behavior you are seeing will happen when 'email' is not set in session at all. So the test in template to check whether it is set is not session['email'] == None , but is closer to 'email' in session and len(session['email']) > 0

Comment: How would you place it in jinja?

Comment: So what I did was ```{% if not session['email'] %}``` and it works. I don't know whether was it you detailed above.